# c compiler for python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, compilation

I want to install `python-igraph`. I need `c/c++ compiler` for it, how can I install `c compiler` in `windows` for `python`? and how can I link python-igraph to this compiler?
I installed `Mingw` but then I don't know how should I set variable for it?

edit: I want to run [this tool](https://github.com/levilucio/SyVOLT). one of its requirements is installing python-igraph. When I run [this file](https://github.com/levilucio/SyVOLT/blob/master/eclipse_integration/verify_fam_extended.xml) I have the below error:

```
 File "toplevel.py", line 37
 self.transformation_directory = "C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\Workspace1\test3\backend\generated/transformation"
                                         ^
 SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

some one tell me this is because the c/c++ compiler didn't install in your PC.
I also search about this error, but the solutions are depended on I know the source code of this tool. but I didn't know about source code I just change line 6 and 73 of above file.

I use windows 8 (I have the same error on windows vista).

My system Path variable is:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35;C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts;C:\Program Files\pl\bin;

My user path variable is:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install igraph for python on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113151/how-to-install-igraph-for-python-on-windows)

Comment: @NetVicious I asked another question. I have a problem with installing  c compiler, not python-igraph. I installed python-igraph, but it seems it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Ok, the question was not very good writed so. What variable you're talking about. The path variable you should modify? Which Windows version are you running?

Comment: @NetVicious thanks. I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

In python you should use double backslash for path delimiters.

You're receiving that message because `\U` it's used for extended Unicode codepoint escape.

Try with this:

```
self.transformation_directory = "C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\Workspace1\\test3\\backend\\generated\\transformation"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it compatible with python3.5? how can I install it?