# Python iterate through connected components in grayscale image

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, connected-components

I have a gray scale image with values between 0 (black) and white (255). I have a `target` matrix of the same size as the gray scale image. I need to start at a random pixel in the gray scale image and traverse through the image one pixel at a time (in a depth-first search manner), copying its value to the corresponding location in the `target` matrix. I obviously need to do this only for the non-white pixels. How can I do this? I thought that I could get the connected components of the gray scale image and traverse each pixel one by one, but I couldn't find any suitable implementation of connected components. Any ideas?

For example, if my gray scale image is:

```
[[255,255,255,255,255,255,255]
[255,255, 0 ,10 ,255,255, 1 ]
[255,30 ,255,255,50 ,255, 9 ]
[51 ,20 ,255,255, 9 ,255,240]
[255,255,80 ,50 ,170,255, 20]
[255,255,255,255,255,255, 0 ]
[255,255,255,255,255,255, 69]]
```

Then a possible traversal is `[0,10,50,9,170,50,80,20,51,30]` followed by `[1,9,240,20,0,69]` to give `[0,10,50,9,170,50,80,20,51,30,1,9,240,20,0,69]`. The order between the different objects doesn't matter.

Other possible traversals are:
`[1,9,240,20,0,69,0,10,50,9,170,50,80,20,51,30]` or `[1,9,240,20,0,69,0,10,50,9,170,50,80,20,30,51]` or
`[1,9,240,20,0,69,10,50,9,170,50,80,20,30,0,51]`

etc.

Comment: Could you add some example data? I read the question now 5 times and I don't see the problem of using two nested for loops with a random start and excluding by copying only values != 255. Maybe specify the question a bit more.

Comment: Added an example. I can't just copy non-255 values because that wouldn't be depth-first search

Comment: Your example has values between 0 and 1 and in question, you are saying the grayscale image has values between 0 and 255. Also, why do you require `dfs`?

Comment: I perceive *"depth first"* to mean you go down a hierarchy of, say, directories first before worrying about the contents of each directory. What do you mean in a flat, non-hierarchical image by *"depth first"*?

Comment: @KartikeySingh fixed the example!

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes. In this case, by depth first I mean this: start at a pixel and traverse adjoining pixels in a depth first manner (i.e. continue to just go to any connected pixel and keep going until a pixel has no more unvisited connected pixels. Then go back to previous pixels and see if they have any unvisited neighbours and continue this process till all non-white pixels have been visited)

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by *"depth first"* and your example is poor because there is only one *"object"* in the image and it is only one pixel thick so there is little choice about which pixel to take next. Maybe you could add a diagram with 2 fatter objects and number the order to copy across, or draw a line tracing out the order. Thanks.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to explain that he actually wants to search a path in a maze using a depth-first approach where the path is defined by black pixels.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added.

Comment: @Dawid, yes but not only black pixels. Any non-white pixels.

Comment: I still don't understand. If your first pixel is 240 and the second one is 9, can the third one be 20?

Comment: No, that is not depth-first search. Think about the depth-first search algorithm for a graph

Comment: So, your example presumably corresponds to the digits `01`? Have you managed to at least write the code that splits the `0` from the `1`? Where's that please?

Comment: Please tell me a possible traversal beginning with 240.

Comment: `240,9,1,20,0,69,0,10,50,9,170,50,80,20,51,30`

Comment: I had the same problem with poor documentations of connected component. Actually `networkx` has a pretty good one but performance is really slow and unsatisfactory for me. Then I have found a solution using `igraph`. I'm going to describe it asap.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `networkx`:

```
from itertools import product, repeat
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

arr = np.array(
[[255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
 [255,255, 0 ,10 ,255,255, 1 ],
 [255,30 ,255,255,50 ,255, 9 ],
 [51 ,20 ,255,255, 9 ,255,240],
 [255,255,80 ,50 ,170,255, 20],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255, 0 ],
 [255,255,255,255,255,255, 69]])

# generate edges
shift = list(product(*repeat([-1, 0, 1], 2)))
x_max, y_max = arr.shape
edges = []

for x, y in np.ndindex(arr.shape):
    for x_delta, y_delta in shift:
        x_neighb = x + x_delta
        y_neighb = y + y_delta
        if (0 <= x_neighb < x_max) and (0 <= y_neighb < y_max):
            edge = (x, y), (x_neighb, y_neighb)
            edges.append(edge)

# build graph
G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)

# draw graph
pos = {(x, y): (y, x_max-x) for x, y in G.nodes()}
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=pos, node_color='coral', node_size=1000)
```

[image]

```
# draw graph with numbers
labels = dict(np.ndenumerate(arr))
node_color = ['coral' if labels[n] == 255 else 'lightgrey' for n in G.nodes()]
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=pos, labels=labels, node_color=node_color, node_size=1000)
```

[image]

```
# build subgraph
select = np.argwhere(arr < 255)
G1 = G.subgraph(map(tuple, select))

# draw subgraph
pos = {(x, y): (y, x_max-x) for x, y in G1.nodes()}
labels1 = {n:labels[n] for n in G1.nodes()}
nx.draw(G1, with_labels=True, pos=pos, labels=labels1, node_color='lightgrey', node_size=1000)
```

[image]

```
# find connected components and DFS trees
for i in nx.connected_components(G1):
    source = next(iter(i))
    idx = nx.dfs_tree(G1, source=source)
    print(arr[tuple(np.array(idx).T)])
```

Output:

```
[  0  10  50   9  50  80  20  30  51 170]
[  9   1 240  20   0  69]
```

Comment: That looks very elegant!

Answer (score 3):

So after so much researches for suitable implementation of connected components, I came up with my solution. In order to reach the best I can do in terms of performance, I relied on these rules:

1. Not to use `networkx` because it's slow according to this [benchmark](https://www.timlrx.com/2019/05/05/benchmark-of-popular-graph-network-packages/)
2. Use vectorized actions as much as possible because Python based iterations are slow according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755634/3044825).

I'm implementing an algorithm of connected components of image here only because I believe this is an essential part of this question.

#### Algorithm of connected components of image

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
import pandas as pd
import igraph

def get_coords(arr):
    x, y = np.indices(arr.shape)
    mask = arr != 255
    return  np.array([x[mask], y[mask]]).T

def compare(r1, r2):
    #assuming r1 is a sorted array, returns:
    # 1) locations of r2 items in r1
    # 2) mask array of these locations
    idx = np.searchsorted(r1, r2)
    idx[idx == len(r1)] = 0
    mask = r1[idx] == r2
    return idx, mask

def get_reduction(coords, s):
    d = {'s': s, 'c0': coords[:,0], 'c1': coords[:,1]}
    return ne.evaluate('c0*s+c1', d)

def get_bounds(coords, increment):
    return np.max(coords[1]) + 1 + increment

def get_shift_intersections(coords, shifts):
    # instance that consists of neighbours found for each node [[0,1,2],...]
    s = get_bounds(coords, 10)
    rdim = get_reduction(coords, s)
    shift_mask, shift_idx = [], []
    for sh in shifts:
        sh_rdim = get_reduction(coords + sh, s)
        sh_idx, sh_mask = compare(rdim, sh_rdim)
        shift_idx.append(sh_idx)
        shift_mask.append(sh_mask)
    return np.array(shift_idx).T, np.array(shift_mask).T,

def connected_components(coords, shifts):
    shift_idx, shift_mask = get_shift_intersections(coords, shifts)
    x, y = np.indices((len(shift_idx), len(shift_idx[0])))
    vertices = np.arange(len(coords))
    edges = np.array([x[shift_mask], shift_idx[shift_mask]]).T

    graph = igraph.Graph()
    graph.add_vertices(vertices)
    graph.add_edges(edges)
    graph_tags = graph.clusters().membership
    values = pd.DataFrame(graph_tags).groupby([0]).indices
    return values

coords = get_coords(arr)
shifts=((0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(-1,1))
comps = connected_components(coords, shifts=shifts)

for c in comps:
    print(coords[comps[c]].tolist())
```

#### Outcome

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 4], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 4], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
[[1, 6], [2, 6], [3, 6], [4, 6], [5, 6], [6, 6]]
```

#### Explanation

Algorithm consists of these steps:

- We need to convert image to coordinates of non-white cells. It can be done using function:

  ```
  def get_coords(arr):
      x, y = np.indices(arr.shape)
      mask = arr != 255
      return np.array([y[mask], x[mask]]).T
  ```

  I'll name an outputting array by `X` for clarity. Here is an output of this array, visually:

  [image]
- Next, we need to consider all the cells of each shift that intersects with `X`:

  [image]

  In order to do that, we should solve a [problem of intersections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656759/) I posted few days before. I found it [quite difficult to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array/38674038#38674038) using multidimensional `numpy` arrays. Thanks to Divakar, he proposes [a nice way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59336298/3044825) of dimensionality reduction using `numexpr` package which fastens operations even more than `numpy`. I implement it here in this function:

  ```
  def get_reduction(coords, s):
      d = {'s': s, 'c0': coords[:,0], 'c1': coords[:,1]}
      return ne.evaluate('c0*s+c1', d)
  ```

  In order to make it working, we should set a bound `s` which can be calculated automatically using a function

  ```
  def get_bounds(coords, increment):
      return np.max(coords[1]) + 1 + increment
  ```

  or inputted manually. Since algorithm requires increasing coordinates, pairs 
  of coordinates might be out of bounds, therefore I have used a slight `increment` here. Finally, as a solution to my post I mentioned here, indexes of coordinates of `X` (reduced to 1D), that intersects with any other array of coordinates `Y` (also reduced to 1D) can be accessed via function

  ```
  def compare(r1, r2):
      # assuming r1 is a sorted array, returns:
      # 1) locations of r2 items in r1
      # 2) mask array of these locations
      idx = np.searchsorted(r1, r2)
      idx[idx == len(r1)] = 0
      mask = r1[idx] == r2
      return idx, mask
  ```
- Plugging all the corresponding `arrays` of shifts. As we can see, abovementioned function outputs two variables: an array of index locations in the main set `X` and its mask array. A proper indexes can be found using `idx[mask]` and since this procedure is being applied for each shift, I implemented `get_shift_intersections(coords, shifts)` method for this case.
- Final: constructing nodes & edges and taking output from `igraph`. The point here is that `igraph` performs well only with nodes that are consecutive integers starting from 0. That's why my script was designed to use mask-based access to item locations in `X`. I'll explain briefly how did I use `igraph` here:

  - I have calculated coordinate pairs:

    ```
      [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 6], [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, 6], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 4], [3, 6], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 6], [5, 6], [6, 6]]
    ```
  - Then I assigned integers for them:

    ```
      [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
    ```
  - My edges looks like this:

    ```
      [[0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 7], [3, 0], [4, 8], [5, 9], [6, 7], [6, 3], [7, 10], [8, 12], [9, 13], [10, 11], [11, 12], [11, 8], [13, 14], [14, 15]]
    ```
  - Output of `graph.clusters().membership` looks like this:

    ```
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    ```
  - And finally, I have used `groupby` method of `Pandas` to find indexes of separate groups (I use Pandas here because I found it to be the most efficient way of grouping in Python)

#### Notes

Download of `igraph` [is not straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113151/how-to-install-igraph-for-python-on-windows), you might need to install it from unofficial binaries.

Comment: So much work and OP hasn't even upvoted it. So you used intersection to get those subgraphs?

Comment: Yes, I've been iterating through each shift of non-white cells and used intersection of initial cells with shifted cells as a masking operation. Resulting arrays are of the equal length and can be saved as a `numpy` matrix.