# What is a best way to intersect multiple arrays with numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an example of `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([2,5,0,4,3,1])
```

And I also have a list of arrays, like:

```
A = [np.array([-2,0,2]), np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([2,5,4,6])]
```

I want to leave only these items of each list that are also in X. I expect also to do it in a most efficient/common way.

Solution I have tried so far:

1. Sort `X` using `X.sort()`.
2. Find locations of items of each array in `X` using:

   ```
   locations = [np.searchsorted(X, n) for n in A]
   ```
3. Leave only proper ones:

   ```
   masks = [X[locations[i]] == A[i] for i in range(len(A))]
   result = [A[i][masks[i]] for i in range(len(A))]
   ```

But it doesn't work because locations of third array is out of bounds:

```
locations = [array([0, 0, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64), array([2, 5, 4, 6], dtype=int64)]
```

How to solve this issue?

#### Update

I ended up with `idx[idx==len(Xs)] = 0` solution. I've also noticed two different approaches posted between the answers: transforming `X` into `set` vs `np.sort`. Both of them has plusses and minuses: `set` operations uses iterations which is [quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755442/what-is-vectorization/47755634) in compare with `numpy` methods; however `np.searchsorted` speed increases logarithmically unlike acceses of `set` items which is instant. That why I decided to compare performance using data with huge sizes, especially 1 million items for `X, A[0], A[1], A[2]`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be less compute and minimal work when looping. So, here's one with those in mind -

```
a = np.concatenate(A)
m = np.isin(a,X)
l = np.array(list(map(len,A)))
a_m = a[m]
cut_idx = np.r_[0,l.cumsum()]
l_m = np.add.reduceat(m,cut_idx[:-1])
cl_m = np.r_[0,l_m.cumsum()]
out = [a_m[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(cl_m[:-1],cl_m[1:])]
```

**Alternative #1 :**

We can also use `np.searchsorted` to get the `isin` mask, like so -

```
Xs = np.sort(X)
idx = np.searchsorted(Xs,a)
idx[idx==len(Xs)] = 0
m = Xs[idx]==a
```

**Another way with `np.intersect1d`**

If you are looking for the most common/elegant one, think it would be with `np.intersect1d` -

```
In [43]: [np.intersect1d(X,A_i) for A_i in A]
Out[43]: [array([0, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([2, 4, 5])]
```

---

**Solving your issue**

You can also solve your out-of-bounds issue, with a simple fix -

```
for l in locations:
    l[l==len(X)]=0
```

Comment: I'm sure using `intersect1d` is a good expression of my idea but I work with pretty huge `X` and `A` so that's why I have decided to sort `X` first.

Comment: @mathfux I think you'll find sorting very large arrays is much slower than using `set` functions.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, very simple and efficent:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([2,5,0,4,3,1])
A = [np.array([-2,0,2]), np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([2,5,4,6])]

X_set = set(X)
A = [np.array([a for a in arr if a in X_set]) for arr in A]
#[array([0, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([2, 5, 4])]
```

According to the [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), set operations all have `O(1)` complexity, therefore the overall is `O(N)`