# Numpy - get mask from shape and indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, mask

After using `np.instersect1d` I have retrieved the indices that I want to retrieve. I want to turn these indices into a mask so I can then combine it with another mask.

What I am wanting:

```
>>> times_1.shape
... (160,)

>>> _, time_indices, _ = np.intersect1d(times_1, times_2, return_indices=True)

>>> time_indices.shape
... (145,)

    # Some way to turn return mask from original shape and indices
>>> time_mask = get_mask_from_shape(time_1.shape, time_indices)

>>> time_mask.shape
... (160,)
```

What would be the simplest way to implement the function `get_mask_from_shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is:

```
time_mask = np.zeros(times_1.shape, dtype=bool)
time_mask[time_indices] = True
```

Answer (score -1):

If I get an idea right, I would apply this pattern I've been looking for a [few days before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656759/):

```
intersection = np.intersect1d(times_1, times_2)
intersection = np.sort(intersection)
locations = np.searchsorted(intersection, times_1)
locations[locations==len(intersection)] = 0
time_mask = intersection[locations]==times_1
```

`searchsorted` method finds indices where elements of `times_1` should be inserted into `intersection` to maintain order, according to [`numpy` documentation.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

Comment: Answer is fairly long winded, would be good to have the answer be a few lines...

Comment: Was the output as you expected?

Comment: This is massive overkill. You are performing very expensive operations unnecessarily. Why are you sorting and searching?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandings. My method is efficient only if intersections were used repeatedly with the same array.