# Check intersection between each element in array of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension, intersection

In Python, I have a list of different size arrays. I would like to know the intersection for all arrays contained in the list. For instance:

```
import numpy as np

array0 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
array1 = [0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array2 = [4,5,6]
array3 = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

array_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]
```

I want to use a function like `np.intersect1d` across all of the arrays in `array_list` and get the intersection across all data arrays. From a quick glance, the answer would be

```
intersection = np.array([5,6])
```

I've tried using list comprehension, something like:

```
np.intersect1d([arraylist[x] for x in np.arange(len(arraylist))]),
```

but Numpy expects 2 arguments instead of the one I'm providing. For a similar reason,

```
list(filter(lambda x:x in [x for x in arraylist]))
```

will not work -- `filter` expects 2 arguments, and is only getting one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a best way to intersect multiple arrays with numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656759/what-is-a-best-way-to-intersect-multiple-arrays-with-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  `reduce()`  from `functools` module to intersect multiple lists with `np.intersect1d`:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

array0 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
array1 = [0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array2 = [4,5,6]
array3 = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

array_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]

print(reduce(np.intersect1d,[array0, array1, array2, array3] ))
```

output:-

```
[5 6]
```

or use `sets` to intersect them

```
import numpy as np

array0 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
array1 = [0,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array2 = [4,5,6]
array3 = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
    
array_list = [array0, array1, array2, array3]

print(set.intersection(*map(set,array_list)))
```

output:-

```
{5,6}
```

Comment: Dang, I knew about `set`, but thought that was for individual lists. This works great, thanks1

Comment: @AaronJPung yup, you can use it with multiple lists with the help of `map()`  function.